# JavaFX Spinner - How to set min, max and value later in the code?

Tags: javafx, spinner

Say, for example, you are implementing pagination. The Spinner might have initialized and added to an HBox or similar in the initialization part of the screen. After the data is retrieved only you would come to know how many pages are needed and according to that only can set the spinner's min and max. I couldn't find a way to re-initialize or say set these later. Am I looking at the usage wrong?

Comment: how about reading the api doc ;) and one problem per question

Comment: hint: the spinner is backed by a spinnerValueFactory

Comment: I spent hours in the API doc. It's not talking about setting it after initialization. Not sure why you downgraded the question. If you know an API doc answering it, please share. I was looking at the oracle doc. Also, I can remove the second question of alignment and ask a separate question, but the thought is kind of related to it as when you set the left and right buttons to move the spinner, you would expect the text to be in the center - which is not the case - and couldn't find an alignment property.

Comment: @kleopatra - I verified the documentation again - the only way to set the min and max of the spinner is when it's initialized. The value factory can be used to set value (like current value) but how to set its min and max as we figure it out at a later stage is unclear in the documentation. I could find a lot of constructors but nothing else.

Comment: the rule is one problem per question, period. Please read the how to ask help pages to understand why (hint: it's _not you_ who is in focus, but _future_ readers ;)

Comment: OK, removed the second question, now if you don't mind please upvote the question as it could help someone. I was not aware of that rule, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out: Thanks @kleopatra for the hint:

If you have an Integer Spinner, you can set:

```
spinner.setValueFactory(
    new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(
        min, 
        max
    )
);
```

Where min and max are decided later in the code.

You can also add an optional third parameter to the constructor to set the value if you wish.

The above code did the job. May be helpful to someone.

Comment: “I still couldn't find how to align text” -> Then ask a new question about alignment which includes a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: Sure, doing it. I have removed the second question from the original question. I was not aware of the one problem per question rule. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution for the integer spinner:

```java
SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory = (SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory) spinner.getValueFactory();
valueFactory.setMax(10);
valueFactory.setMax(5);
```